# how to open a file using IF in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop

I would like to write a code which open more than one .xlsx files, depending the conditions. I wrote this one:

```
Sub Macro()
    Dim ColumnNumb As Integer
    Dim FileName(14 To 16) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    ColumnNumb = 2

    For i = 14 To 16
        FileName(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value
        If Workbooks("Book1.xlsm").Worksheets("Input").Cells(14, ColumnNumb) = "Yes" Then
            Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\Excel\" & FileName(i), UpdateLinks:=3
            'MsgBox FileName(i)
         End If
    Next i 
End Sub
```

The "Workbooks.Open..." line which is not working. However I use only the next line (MsgBox) instead of "Workbooks.Open...", then it is working perfectly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is not working ? are you getting an error ?

Comment: It is running, but there is no results (opened file or error msg). Previously the loop opened the first file then I got an error msg: run time error: 1004 Path & " could not be found"...

Comment: `Cells(i, 1)` uses the currently active sheet if you don't specify the sheet like in the if statement, so that might be one of the problems.

Comment: @Csaba Csorba try the code in my answer below, let me know if it's working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below.

Once you open the File you lose your `ActiveSheet`, so the line `FileName(i) = Cells(i, 1).Value` won't work on the second time.

```
Sub Macro()

Dim ColumnNumb As Integer
Dim FileName(14 To 16) As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim ThisWB  As Workbook
Dim Sht As Worksheet

ColumnNumb = 2

Set ThisWB = ThisWorkbook
' I assume from your post your data is in "Input" sheet >> modify to your needs
Set Sht = ThisWB.Sheets("Input")

For i = 14 To 16
    FileName(i) = Sht.Cells(i, 1).Value

    If Sht.Cells(14, ColumnNumb) = "Yes" Then
        Workbooks.Open FileName:="C:\Excel\" & FileName(i), UpdateLinks:=3
        'MsgBox FileName(i)
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much it is working. I totally forgot to change the active worksheet. Thanks again! Csaba